# VMWare Workstation VM Windows with static IP has no Internet Access

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, nat, vmware-workstation

I've looked for answers first because it is probably basic e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/220539/cannot-using-internet-in-vmware

problem: on my vmware client machine (windows server 2008R2) I can serve websites (iis) but can not connect to the internet, however when I set it to DHCP i CAN access the internet (however dont want DHCP...)

My Host "Local Area Connection" is set fixed to (and can access internet):

- IP: 192.168.1.49
- Subnet: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.1.1 (my router)
- DNS: 192.168.1.1 (my router)
- Alternative: 8.8.8.8 (google)

My VMWare's client "Local Area Connection" is to:

- IP: 192.168.1.50
- Subnet: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.1.1
- DNS: 192.168.1.1
- Alternative: 8.8.8.8

(these are the same settings as the laptop next to it running the same configuration and which can server sites and can access the internet)

I've tried switching the gateways to the host, switching from nat to bridged, so far no luck.

dns resolution seems to work since a ping to whatever.xxx gives me the correct IP adress , however the Reply from <192.168.1.50>: Destination host unreachable.

update: i can access my local lan websites on 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.70 via the browser. Only everything externally = no connection to the internet, while on the host I can.
update: i notice ipconfig gives me as default gateway: 0.0.0.0 and then 192.168.1.1 where does the 0.0.0.0 come from?

Comment: VMware is a company, not a product. Exactly what are you running?

Comment: vmware workstation

Comment: Set the IP configuration you've posted above and then power down the VM. Then set the VM's NIC to bridged mode and power it back on and report the results.

Comment: unfortunately idem ping returns the correct ip but destination unreachable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually a Windows Server 2008 R2 problem and NOT a VMware problem....... (was searching totally in the wrong direction)

For those searching:

1. disable the NIC (!)
2. regedit HKLM - SYSTEM - CurrentControlSet - services - Tcpip - Parameters - Interfaces
3. remove all "DefaultGateway" entries but one and make sure there is only one value in there
4. re-enable the NIC

Working....